# VBA - Decimal to Time - Wrong value no matter what

Tags: vba, time, decimal

I'm new to this community so please critizise all you want on this post, if I make any rookie mistakes.

I'm currently stuck on an assignment. I am somewhat new to visual basic, but my understanding so far has been fairly good. However, I can not seem to get a basic operation sorted. I have searched the internet and bashed my head against the wall for a day or two now. Hopefully, you can help me sort this out.

I am importing cycle times for different orders from an Oracle database. They are returned into a column as decimal values (number of hours), but I want them shown as "Long Time" ("hh:mm:ss"). What I have read, it should be as easy as dividing by 24 and changing the format. However, this gives the wrong values when using the cell values.

Example:

```
? ws.Cells(i,6) 'Cycle times are placed in column 6 while looping over rows i.
0.050000
? Format(0.050000/24, "hh:mm:ss")
00:03:00
```

but

```
? Format(ws.Cells(i,6)/24,"hh:mm:ss")
08:00:00
```

which is clearly not correct. 0.05 hours equivalent to 3 minutes. I have observed a change in date value as well:

```
? Format(0.05/24, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
1899-12-30 00:03:00

? Format(ws.Cells(i,6)/24, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
1905-09-13 08:00:00
```

**How is this even possible!?** `ws.Cells(i,6)` returns 0.05. Despite this `Format(ws.Cells(i,6)/24,"hh:mm:ss")`≠`Format(0.05/24,"hh:mm:ss")`

I've tried messing around with number formats (strings, dates etc.), `.Value` and `.Value2`

Does anybody know what is going on and why this is happening?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: `? Format(ws.Cells(i,6)/24,"hh:mm:ss")` gives me `00:03:00`

Comment: Try manually typing that in a new workbook and see if you are getting the same result?

Comment: Is the value of `i` the same when you are doing `? ws.Cells(i,6)` and when you are doing `? Format(ws.Cells(i,6)/24,"hh:mm:ss")`?  It's also interesting that it is showing `0.050000` and not `0.05` as the answer to `? ws.Cells(i,6)`.

Comment: It's also interesting that `1905-09-13 08:00:00` * 24 gives 50000.  What language version of Excel are you using?  And what locale are you using?
  Do you use `.` as a decimal point, or do you use `.` as a thousands separator?

Comment: @YowE3K, I was lazy and unclear. `? ws.Cells(i,6)` does indeed return `0.05000`.  Sorry about that.


@SiddharthRout, I manually typed in 0.050000 in a new workbook and tried `? Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(2,6)/24, "hh.mm:ss")`. Still returns 8 hours.

Comment: Ok do this... Click on `File|Options|Advanced`.  Is `Use 1904 data system check box` checked under the `When calculating this workbook` If yes then uncheck it. Close the workbook and reopen it and try again.

Comment: @Smartskaft2 - the fact that `? ws.Cells(i,6)` returns `0.050000` and not `0.05` means that it is not numeric - Excel is thinking it is text.  And it is probably thinking it is text because `0.050000` is not a valid number in your locale.

Comment: @YowE3K Even if it is text you will still get `00:03:00` :)

Comment: @YowE3K, I use `.` as a decimal point. I do not know what language I am using. I am working in the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, Office 2013.

Comment: @SiddharthRout You will get `00:03:00` **if** you are using `.` as a decimal point, but if your locale uses it as a thousands separator it will think you are doing `50000/24` which gives a date/time of `1905-09-13 08:00:00`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, the checkbox you mentioned was not checked.

Comment: @YowE3K: Good point!. :)

Comment: What happens if you replace the `.` with `,` in that cell?

Comment: @YowE3K Ah right. That explains it. I'll try to change it and try again.

Comment: if that works then @YowE3K you might want to put it as an answer :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm not sure what the "answer" will actually be - if the locale is using `.` as the decimal point, it shouldn't be treating it as `50000`, it should be treating it as `0.05`.

Comment: @Smartskaft2 Try writing a formula in Excel somewhere saying `=VALUE(F2)*1` - I would be interested to see whether it shows `0.05` or `50000`.  Then format that cell (the one with the formula) to display in Number format, with two decimal places, and with thousands separator, and see how it displays.

Comment: Hmm. `Application.DecimalSeparator` returns a `,` (not a `.` which I was assuming was used. However, `Application.ThousandsSeparator` returns nothing. (Also, `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True`)

Is it safe to change the decimal separator in VBA? 

What I don't understand is how it is used. I've always used the `.` for typing in decimal values. Is the decimal separator only used while reading strings, cell values etc.?

Comment: `=VALUE(F2)*1` returns `#VALUE!` (A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type.)

Comment: If I manually change the cells value from `0.050000` to `0,050000`, both that cell and the one with the formula `=VALUE(F2)*1` returns `0,05`. So I guess it s an issue of decimal seperator.

Comment: So Excel isn't recognising `0.050000` as a valid numeric value (although it might accept `10.050000` as being `10050000`)

Comment: Check your computer's Settings / Time & Language settings.  It sounds like you're not located where you think you are located.  (Maybe someone sent you for an overseas holiday and forget to tell you :D)

Comment: Yes, `? Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(2,6)/24,"hh:mm:ss")` returns `00:03:00` now that I changed the cell to `0,050000`. 

Can I safely change the seperator by `Application.DecimalSeparator = "."`, or is it better to substitute the `.` with `,`?

Comment: I think it would be safer to check your computer's settings, unless you are sure that it is **only** in Excel that you are having the issue.  I'm not sure how many places the locale can be set - it might be a computer setting **and** an Excel setting **and** a workbook setting.  But I would start by checking the computer settings first.

Comment: I'm not sure whether `DecimalSeparator` gets saved into the next time you open Excel - changing it might only be effective while in the current instance, or it may be changing your system settings - I really don't know.  Unfortunately, I have to call it a night now so all I can suggest is check out the MSDN documention on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, both of you! It really saved a lot more time. It drove me crazy.

Have a good night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that your computer is thinking that `0.050000` is not actually the number `0.05` but is actually a string that is being interpreted as `50000`.

Thus, when you divide 50000 by 12, you get the date/time of `1905-09-13 08:00:00` which is then displayed as just `08:00:00` when a `"hh:mm:ss"` format is used.

I think you need to check your date/time & language settings to ensure that they are set correctly.

Comment: Correct. This was indeed the case. My solution was to substitute the `.` in the cells with `,`. Unless I run into more of these situations, I do not want to mess with the default settings. 

Thank you!